# Как убрать у числа пробел JS

Tags: javascript

Есть функция parseInt(max30, 10); преобразует строки вида 1100 в число. Но бывает встречается стока записанная вот так 1 100, пробел мешает, выдает NaN... Как можно преобразовать строки такого вида в число? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так. С помощью регулярного выражения. Приведу полный код документа.

```js
var s="1 1100";
s = s.replace(/\s/g, '');
document.write(s);
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Пробовал так, консоль ошибку выдает, есть еще вариант?

Comment: TypeError: str.replace is not a function

Comment: Приложил полный код HTML.

Comment: var max10 = $(".tr11:nth-child(1) span").text();
                        max10.replace(/\s/g, '');
                        parseInt(max10, 10);

Comment: Может я что то делаю не так?

Comment: Выполните преобразование max10 в строку.

Answer (score 1):

Так же можно и без регулярок, но еще нужно выяснить что лучше:

```js
let s = '1 1100';
s = +s.split(' ').join('');
document.write(s);
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Понять не могу, почему у вас работает у меня нет...

Comment: @ilyaaa521 браузер? ошибки?

Comment: Mozilla, var s = $(".tr11 span");
s = +s.split(' ').join('');
alert(s)
TypeError: s.split is not a function

Comment: var s = $(".tr11 span").text();
s = +s.split(' ').join('');
parseInt(s);
alert(s)  - сделал так, пишет NaN

Comment: выведите `$(".tr11 span").text()` в консоль

Comment: var s = $(".tr11:nth-child(1) span").text()
console.log(s); - выводит число с пробелом

Comment: var s = $(".tr11:nth-child(1) span").text();
s = +s.split(' ').join('');
console.log(s);
undefined
NaN  -  если так то пишет NaN

Comment: Даже если спарсить в число всеравно NaN

Comment: @ilyaaa521 конктрентый вывод скопируйте сюда

Comment: var s = $(".tr11:nth-child(1) span").text();
s = +s.split(' ').join('');
parseInt(s);
console.log(s);
undefined
NaN

Comment: мне только входной текст интересен `console.log($(".tr11:nth-child(1) span").text())`

Comment: var max10 = $(".tr11:nth-child(1) span").text();
                        max10 = max10.replace(/\s/g, '');
                        parseInt(max10,10);  -  рабочий вариант, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```js
function parse(x) {
  var res = +x;
  return res === res ? res : +(""+x).replace(/\s/g, "")
}

console.log([
  123, "123", "1 234", "-2.5",
  0, "0", "", null,
  undefined, NaN, "null", "qwe",
].map(parse).join(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо удаления пробелов из строки - я бы сделал удаление всех нечисловых символов (исключая минус, и точку как разделитель целой и дробной частей числа), а затем взятие числа до точки... то есть, заодно еще и операцию `floor` выполнив. Имхо, это более целесообразно.

```js
for (const s of ['1 100', '-$12,000', '\n123abc', '45.678'])
  console.log(parseIntEx(s)); 

function parseIntEx(val) {
  const match = val.replace(/[^\d.\-]/g, '').match(/^(-?\d+)(?:\.)?/); 
  return (match || [0, null])[1]; 
}
```

Единственное "но": при входной строке вида `'ab-cd123'`, результат будет некорректен: `-123`. Такой случай можно обработать, но ценой усложнения.